# React app, API call, SSL and connection error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, ssl, tls1.2

I have an React JS application which calls a Java backend for validating some data. The call is to an HTTP POST method exposed in the Spring boot service which is exposed behind a (OCP) router which has is SSL enabled. From router to Spring boot API is plain HTTP call. But when call is made to API through router, then following error is occurring.

```
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I tried following -

1. I added the router certificate to browser, it did not resolve.
2. Then I added CA certificate chain of the organization to router, which is already available in the browser, but still I get the above error.
3. I can execute this API from the Postman successfully.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean OCP or OPC?

Comment: I meant Openshift (kubernetes) cluster

Comment: You can execute in Postman ? May be disabled the SSL verification option ?. You shouldn't add the router certificate to browser. For browser to talk to https url you should add the CA certificate chain(used for signing the router's certificate) to the browser.